# Packing objects in column evenly

Tags: algorithm, packing

I have 4 columns that I need to fill as with boxes. The boxes can be of varying sizes, and they must be in the correct order- ordered top to bottom first and then left to right.

So:

AA  CC
AA  CC
BB  CC
BB

for the first two columns. Finally I would like the length of the columns to be as similar as possible.

Is there any algorithm I can use to achieve this? I've read some stuff on packing algorithms but I don't know how to match that with the even-ness rule!

Comment: Are your number of columns fixed at 4? also what is even-ness rule?

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: Number of columns are fixed at 4 but a general solution to a system with a set amount of columns would be nice too. Sorry about the even-ness rule that was me re-iterating that the length of the columns should be as similar as possible.

Comment: "The boxes can be of varying sizes"...so it seems that there are cells of some width and height that you need to fill in your table ? or can we assume that all boxes are same width, height?

Comment: All the same width, varying heights. Sorry that wasnt very clear